# Launching in daemon mode crashes emacs while loading configuration from .org file

Tags: org-babel, emacs24.4, daemon, crash

I've been using literate programming using org-mode for my initialization file. I've a `init.el` which loads a org file converts it to .el and uses it as startup file. [Here](https://github.com/copyninja/dotfiles/tree/master/.emacs.d) is my configuration files. When starting with `--daemon` option emacs crashes if `~/.emacs.d\copyninja-emacs.el` file exists, if I remove it and start it launches fine.

Here is the crash log

```
("/home/vasudev/.emacs.d/copyninja-emacs.org")
Loading /home/vasudev/.emacs.d/copyninja-emacs.el (source)...

Backtrace:
emacs[0x8143ee3]
emacs[0x812a323]
emacs[0x81422ae]
[0xb7774400]
emacs[0x808ec89]
emacs[0x80b0a24]
emacs[0x819dde7]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x819e037]
emacs[0x81a413c]
emacs[0x81a6aeb]
emacs[0x819dde7]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d89e]
emacs[0x819ccdb]
emacs[0x819cff4]
emacs[0x81bc645]
emacs[0x81c0349]
emacs[0x81c0a4d]
emacs[0x819dd8d]
emacs[0x81d1987]
emacs[0x819d81d]
emacs[0x819db63]
emacs[0x819df7f]
emacs[0x81c13ff]
emacs[0x819dd8d]
emacs[0x81d1987]
...
Error: server did not start correctly
```

I'm unable to figure out what is the reason this crash is happening. If some one can point me what might be wrong in my setup it would be great. I use emacs-snapshot package and this used to work fine before and started a couple of month back. I tried emacs from the git and it happens there to.

Comment: Sounds like you should `M-x report-emacs-bug`, but narrow it down if you can. If you take org-mode/babel out of the picture and just use the resulting .el version directly, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Oh, so `copyninja-emacs.el` *is* the 'compiled' version of the org file. Well in that case, start bisecting the file to find out where the problem lies (as long as the problem exists, repeatedly comment out half the remaining un-commented code, until you've narrowed it down).

Comment: I suspect it has to do something with org-babel, because removing .el file makes it load happily. But anyway I will give it a shot by commneting out various part of .org file

Comment: Try the following:  Comment out `(mapc #'org-babel-load-file (directory-files dotfiles-dir t "\\.org$"))` and ensure it loads (while the .el file exists).  Then evaluate that line in the `*scratch*` buffer and see if any errors/prompts occur.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin I tried this, I launched the emacs by commenting `mapc` line and after launching emacs I evaluated that line in scratch and no error occured. Also I noted that this happens only in --daemon mode if I launch emacs directly it works.